# jruby/cucumber: Bundle install doesn't install any gem

Tags: cucumber, bundle, jruby

I'm on Windows 10 x64 and I've installed JRuby 1.7.8 (I tried the files for x64 and 32bits with the same problem) and JRE 7.

I was trying to have my Cucumber Test Framework running on a different machine. I downloaded my current branch (which is working fine in other computers, with all the settings: env.rb, Gemfile, etc) and then I installed successfully these 2 gems:

- gem install bundler
- gem install cucumber

The Gemfile I have contains loads of gems, similar to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "httpclient"
gem "watir-webdriver"
```

but when I execute:

- bundle install

I just get this line and nothing gets installed, it finishes almost immediately. No Gemfile.lock is created, etc.

```
D:\project>bundle install
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated

D:\project>
```

Any idea what could be wrong and what I could try please?

Not quite sure if the issue has anything to do with the line above (which I had never seen in the other machines that are working). If it's not related and you've got an idea about both problems, please let me know and I'll have a look as well...

---

I've been trying for a few more hours and still not success, adding further info in case someone can spot something pls. Even 'bundle -v' doesn't work on this machine?!

```
D:\project>gem list
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.13.2)
cucumber (2.4.0)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
gherkin (4.0.0)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
multi_json (1.12.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
rake (10.1.0)

D:\project>bundle -v
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated

D:\project>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the latest version of bundler 1.13.2 installed and I have seen it cause different types of issues depending on the jruby version and some other gems. Bundler 1.10.6 works everytime for my Jruby 1.7.x.

Try these:

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

and

```
gem install bundler -v 1.10.6
```

Comment: Thanks Sid. 

I was trying to make JRuby work but I was finding issues, I've now moved to Ruby instead, but marking your answer as the solution as it seems to be some kind of incompatibility with versions. I didn't know gems were so sensitive to versions but yes, it seems they are...

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not particularly familiar with jruby, it appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1614), which is resolved in JRuby 1.7.24.

I would verify that the other computers this is working on are still on that version of jruby (assuming they are windows boxes).

Comment: Do you think that error could prevent the command 'bundle' to run?
I was not so concerned about that output line if the the rest works... as I won't be able to check the other machines until mid-week but I wanted to have my local machine working before then...